# Como insertar un excel a un archivo pdf usando itextsharp en wpf?

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, wpf, itextsharp

Hola he estado buscando en internet y no doy con la solución o un ejemplo concreto. Estoy trabajando con la librería itextsharp en wpf para crear un archivo pdf. Ya he creado el archivo pdf y le he agregado información, pero ahora necesito insertar un archivo excel a ese pdf. Alguien me pudiera poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Comment: tal vez lo estás enfocando mal, trata de recuperar e insertar esos datos manualmente, no pasar el excel per sé

Comment: el problema es que es un excel con el q trabaja la compañía, y  debe estar en el pdf que yo he creado con la aplicacion. Consideran que trabajar con el excel y después volver hacer lo mismo en la aplicación seria trabajar doble, pq es obligatorio trabajar con ese excel

Comment: no me entendiste, recupera el excel, lee sus datos e insértalos en el PDF, no intentes tal cual dar un excel y que automáticamente lo metas en un PDF

Comment: ya ok creo que ahora si lo he entendido...tratare de hacer eso...gracias